# Is participle corresponds to "HOW" part of the sentence?

Tags: word-order, sentence-structure, participles

From this (very helpful) [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPyo8-Pr55Q) I learned about the basic structure of a sentence.

WHO > WHAT > WHERE > WHEN > HOW > WHY

Now I'm trying to learn about different word orders. Specifically I'm learning participle.

1. Is it correct to think about participle as the HOW part of the sentence?

E.g.

They ran downstairs looking angry.

WHO  WHAT  WHERE     HOW

or

Looking angry they ran downstairs.

HOW  WHO  WHAT  WHERE

2. The teacher from the video said when you switch the word order the sentence might sound unnatural. Does the second example sound unnatural to a native speaker?

Thanks

Comment: As a teacher, I personally have never tried it and here is the first time I came across. About the unnaturallity of your 2nd example I should say it is not unnatural at all. But I am not a native. Wait 4 them 2 help u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They ran downstairs looking angry.

and

> Looking angry they ran downstairs.
>   *Looking lost, they ran out the door.*

Both sentences are fine and understandable.

The sentence might be rewritten

> Angrily, they ran downstairs.